# How to send email from Error page in IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, asp-classic

I have a custom error page set up in IIS using httperrors.

I need to send out an email simply detailing the page that contained the error.

How can I achieve this? What would be the simplest way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ASP Classic or ASP .Net? Cos the answer will need to be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

If using ASP Classic here's a error handling subroutine that includes a email facility (using CDO.Message). I'd recommend you log your errors to a file or preferably a database, especially if you find you get an unmanageable amount of emails. Plus you can query a log file or database far more efficiently than email.

```
sub geterror
    ' gather details about the error from the ASPError object

    'Dim objasperror, code, num, src, cat
    'Dim line, column, desc, adesc, file

    ' get the last error that occurred!
    set objasperror = server.getlasterror

    ' go through the properties and get whatever you need...
    With objasperror
        code = .aspcode
        num = .number
        src = .source
        cat = .category
        file = .file
        line = .line
        column = .column
        desc = .description
        adesc = .aspdescription
    end With

    ' free ASPError object
    set objasperror = nothing

    ' write the error code
    if code <> "" then errorMSG = (code & vbcrlf)

    ' using hex on the number property gives it
    ' that incomprehensible feel that has always
    ' been associated with ASP Error numbers...
    if num <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & ("0x" & hex(num) & vbcrlf)

    ' source is the line of source code that made the error
    if src <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (src & vbcrlf)

    ' tells you what threw the error - could be IIS, VBScript or whatever...
    if cat <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (cat & vbcrlf)

    ' file is the actual page that crapped out on your site...
    if file <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (file & vbcrlf)

    ' line is the line that failed.
    if line <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (line & vbcrlf)
    if line <> "" then errorLine = errorLine & (line)

    ' column is the character that failed
    if column <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (column & vbcrlf)

    ' returns a description of why the code failed, for
    ' example: variable not defined 'i'
    if desc <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (desc & vbcrlf)
    if desc <> "" THEN errorDesc = errorDesc & (desc)

    ' if the error is an asp error, this property has more info for ya.
    if adesc <> "" then errorMSG = errorMsg & (adesc & vbcrlf)

    if errorMsg = "" THEN
        errorMsg = "not available"
    END IF
    IF errorDesc = "" THEN
        errorDesc = "not available"
    END IF

    for each x in Request.ServerVariables
        errorSV = errorSV & Request.ServerVariables.Key(x) & "=" & Request.ServerVariables.Item(x) & vbcrlf
    next

    'format the above into a readable/helpful email body.
    'also include server variables
    emailbody = errorMSG & errorDesc & errorSV 

    'send an email with the details of the error message
    Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    myMail.From = emailfrom
    myMail.Subject = emailsubject
    myMail.To = emailrecipient
    myMail.BodyPart.ContentTransferEncoding = "quoted-printable"
    myMail.HTMLBody = emailbody
    myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
    'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
    myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")=smtpmailserver
    'Server port
    myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
    myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    myMail.Send
    set myMail=nothing
End Sub

geterror 'calls the error subroutine
```